# How to Navigate between activities within a tab using TabHost

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost

I understand that TabActivity is deprected.
But my situation is like I have an application built entirely using Activities - without any tabs (and no Fragments).
Now, I have to add 3 tabs at the bottom of this appliation. The first tab needs to be used to perform all functionalities of existing app i.e, I need to be able to navigate between all existing activities within the 1st tab. The other 2 tabs will contain 2 new functionalities.

Can any one help me with an approach? [I am against using Fragments since I have to rewrite my application to use Fragments instead of Activities - I hope that's sensible?]

Comment: Converting Activities to Fragments isn't a big task

Answer (score 0):

I'd definitely use fragments, but, if you're against that then you can keep track of the tab selections and set them based on what activity is being called.  For example, while Activity 1/2/3 are being viewed, tab A is selected.  Click tab B and you can navigate within Activities 4/5/6 and keep tab B selected. And so on for tab C with it's Activities.

I'd probably rethink the navigation schema of the app though.

Comment: I found that using a combination of TabActivity and ActivityGroup is one possible option. Details at http://nanostuffs.com/Blog/?p=607